# Is a matrix similar to itself times -1?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A \in M_{2}(\mathbb{Q}) = R$. I don't believe that $A$ is similar to $-A$, but I just want to check. Also, is the only similarity class of matrices in $R$ with exact multiplicative order $4$,  $\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$ and $\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$?

Answer (score 1):

The field is mostly unimportant. $A\in M_2(\mathbb F)$ is similar to $-A$ over a field $\mathbb F$ of characteristic $\ne2$ if and only if $A$ has zero trace.

If $A$ is similar to $-A$, then $\operatorname{tr}(A)=\operatorname{tr}(-A)=-\operatorname{tr}(A)$. Hence $\operatorname{tr}(A)=0$. Conversely, if $\operatorname{tr}(A)=0$, the rational canonical form of $A$ is either $D=\pmatrix{a&0\\ 0&-a}$ for some $a\in\mathbb F$ (when $A$ is diagonalisable) or $C=\pmatrix{0&\det(A)\\ 1&0}$ (when $A$ is non-diagonalisable). Hence $A$ is similar to $-A$, because
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}D\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}=-D
\ \text{ and } \pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}C\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}=-C.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am wrong, the claim is not necessarily true, a counter example is $t = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$, and $x = \left( \begin{matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$. Here $xtx^{-1} = -t$